# javax.jms.JMSException: Could not post command: KeepAliveInfo

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, keep-alive

**Short description of the issue:**

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.10.2 (AMQ) in a project where I have **Application A** sending data over to **Application B** via amq and saw this exception :
`javax.jms.JMSException: Could not post command: KeepAliveInfo`

Here's the full stack trace:

```
ERROR JMSConsumer:148 - Consumer Exception
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not post command: KeepAliveInfo {} due to: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not post command: KeepAliveInfo {} due to: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:33)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.oneway(HttpClientTransport.java:138)
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
```

That exception was seen in **App B** and due to this exception it could not connect to the AMQ.  Restarting the app allowed it to talk to the AMQ again.

Does anyone know how I can reproduce that exception so I can do proper error handling/recovery?

**More details about the issue:**

As mentioned above, I'm trying to recreate the exception to do proper error handling/recovery. But so far I'm unable to reproduce it.

I've looked online and don't see too much on this specific exception nor on the **keepaliveinfo** message other than from activemq's own site.

Per its link https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-inactivitymonitor if the `useInactivityMonitor` parameter is set to `true`, which is the default value, then the apps connecting to that AMQ on the same topic/queue will have that **keepaliveinfo** message sent if it doesn't detect any normal traffic. In my environment that parameter is set to `true`

My thought is, with this value set to true, something happened in my environment (perhaps the AMQ got in a funky state or was low in memory) that it failed to handle a **keepaliveinfo** message sent from my apps and then that jms exception occurred.

In trying to reproduce that exception I have done the following tests to no avail:

### Test 1:

Start **App A, App B** and the AMQ.  After everything is up and running and data is flowing I would then stop the AMQ broker.

I got this exception :

`javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to perform GET on: <my amq ip>:443 Reason: Connection refused: connect`

Which isn't the exception I noticed before.

### Test 2:

I would start **App A, App B**, and the AMQ, and then after everything is up and running I would then stop **App A** (which sends data to **App B** via AMQ).

I did not witness any **keepaliveinfo** messages getting sent and more importantly I don't see the specific jms exception above.

### Test 3:

I started **App B** and the AMQ.  I modified **App A** to connect to the AMQ but commented out the code that sends data to **App B** on the queue/topic.

Again I did not witness this message `JMSException: could not post command: keepaliveinfo`

### Test 4

I modified the AMQ broker activemq.xml file to have its `<memoryUsage> <storeUsage> and <tempUsage>` values to be really low.  In a way to simulate that the ActiveMQ is super busy and can't handle more data being sent.  More info on those parameters are mentioned here https://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html

After restarting AMQ and **App A** and **App B**, I still didn't witness that exception message.

### End of tests

So again, does anyone know what is the setup/conditions on reproducing this issue?

**Extra note:**

It seems like I can avoid this exception altogether if I set the `useInactivityMonitor` parameter to `false`.  With that set then no **keepaliveinfo** messages are sent if no normal traffic occurs over a connection.  But I don't want to change it to false.

And here is my pom file defining the amq artifact id's:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-http</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I updated the post to include the full stack trace and the amq artifacts in my pom file.  In short I'm more focused on this JMSException just because I haven't really been able to reproduce it.  The other ones I've seen have been reproducible so I can code some error handling on them.  But I want to also cover this specific exception.

Comment: Are the `...` sections of the stack-trace what was actually printed or did you remove some details from the stack-trace and insert them? If the latter could you paste the actual, full stack-trace? I'm mainly curious about what JMS API call was made which resulted in the `JMSException`.

Comment: This version was released in 2015, maybe try the latest release as you aren't likely to find many folks willing to dig into code from such an old release.